# How do I put text on a gradient overtop a background video in css?

Tags: html, css, html5-video, gradient

I have a video that plays as the user opens the page so the video is on the background and text can be displayed on top.

This all works right now but I would like to add a `gradient` over the video to make the text at the bottom visible at all times, just like you do with images.

However, I cannot seem to find a solution that worked for me. I'm sorry if the code is a bit unprofessional, I have just started my first year as a student.

```css
.container-video {
  position: relative;
  /* background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
  );
  z-index: 99; */
}

#background-video {
  /* video itself */
  width: 100vw;
  /* viewport width */
  height: 50vh;
  /* viewport height */
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}

.overlay {
  /* text on top of the video */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 280px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-video">
    <video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted poster="images/Placeholder_videoPic.png">
      <source src="videos/Placeholder_Video_trim.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>Meteor dodge</h1>
    <p>Available on PS5, PS5, Xbox & PC</p>
    <p>$14.99</p>
    <a href="inlogForm.html">Kopen</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: margin with `position: absolute;` makes no sense as the element is no longer isndie the flow. what you want is a padding. Then just add the gradient to the overlay not to the parent!

Comment: I changed from margin to padding and added the gradient to the overlay, nothing changed. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: Hi @TiboMertens - this question is still open. Was the question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the CSS that ended up working for me:

```
.container-video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#background-video {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 280px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
  );
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should clearly and logically layer your containers, using `position:absolute` and `z-index`.

Notice, in the HTML, I first created an `outer-container` *(just by adding the `outer-container` class to your existing header)* that defines the box in which the inner containers exist.

This outer container must have `position: nonstatic` *(where "nonstatic" can be "relative", "absolute", "fixed "- anything BUT static - "static" is the default - because the inner containers' `position:absolute` won't work correctly if the outer-container is left at `position:static`).*

Each inner container is then `position: absolute` with top/left/width/height set to the same values. I added classes `container-bottom`, `container-middle`, `container-top` to make it really easy to identify/style them. Then, just use `z-index` to layer them in the desired order.

Note that a middle container was created, on which we put the gradient. That's all that the middle layer/container does.

```js
/* Unnecessary JS that replaces the un-accessible poster/video links FOR THIS DEMO ONLY */
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  $('#background-video').setAttribute('poster', 'https://ourtube.co.uk/upload/photos/2021/11/928b8656defe100bf7c75815db0edf992b1e33d2wK9QTHR7ny9ahCHqPYKf.video_thumb_5245_11.jpeg');
  $('#background-video').removeAttribute('muted');
  $('source').setAttribute('src','https://ourtube.co.uk/upload/videos/2021/11/nHtqkPbgFOHOofoBv7Sr_04_f233dfb6c94f3cc02cf8866c246900b8_video_240p_converted.mp4#t=15');
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#background-video').play();
  },1000);
});
```

```css
.outer-container{
  position:relative;
  width: 99vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
.bottom-container{
  z-index: 0;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.middle-container{
  /* gradient overlay */
  z-index: 1;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99)
  );
}
.top-container{
  z-index: 2;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#background-video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}

.overlay {
  /* text on top of the video */
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  color: yellow;
  xxmargin-top: 280px;
}
a{
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<header class="outer-container">
  <div class="bottom-container container-video">
    <video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted poster="images/Placeholder_videoPic.png">
      <source src="videos/Placeholder_Video_trim.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-container"></div>
  <div class="top-container overlay">
    <div>Meteor Dodge</div>
    <div>Available on PS5, PS5, Xbox & PC</div>
    <div>$14.99</div>
    <a href="inlogForm.html">Kopen</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

*Note that the javascript added to the demo is unnecessary, and serves only to replace the inaccessible (local) links. This was done so that you could see things working as desired. Also, I replaced your H1, P tags with divs only so that they display better in the tiny RunCodeSnippets Demo window.*

Answer (score -1):

You could try to fit a div on top with a low opacity and set the background of that div to the gradient you would like.
Make sure to set `position: relative` to the div.

Kind regards

Emiel